# Can I use different manufacturer’s battery in my Fujitsu laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I have a Fujitsu Lifebook A555 and it's been three complete years using it. Its battery life is very low now i.e. it runs only 30-40 minutes after charging it completely. I searched the web but I couldn't find the battery of the company and model even on the official website of the company.

Can I use a battery of different company with similar specifications in it? Or else if anyone has any idea about where to get the genuine battery of Fujitsu company?

Comment: Regarding the battery there are many sites that you can search; ebay, amazon, even aliexpress, etc. Just do a Google search...
Regarding using battery of different company, different models have different connectors, voltages, etc so you have to with get an OEM version of the battery or the original (from another same model laptop).
Hope this helps.

Comment: If it’s a user replaceable battery, then that means most any battery that matches your laptop’s specs can be used. Just be careful: Many off-brand batteries are worthless and will die or cause problems after a short amount of use. If you get a non-manufacturer battery be sure it’s from a reputable source and supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a Fujitsu battery, you just have to make sure it's compatible with your laptop.

Comment: So, can you recommend some brands which supply reliable batteries?

Comment: Not really - I've had to buy replacement batteries for all kinds of laptops and phones, and I couldn't tell you a single brand or manufacturer. Your best bet is to find the battery on a site you are familiar with or one that is widely known (Amazon, newegg, etc.). If they have a good return policy or reviews available, that would be ideal - otherwise just pick a price point you feel is reasonable.